# How to extract an URL only from .js files

Tags: javascript, sed, grep, cygwin

I would like to extract only text that matches an  URL pattern (without the junk around it) in different `.js` files in the temporary internet files folder (need it for audit purpose).

I have figured I could use:

```
find . -name "*.js" -exec cat {} \; grep 'string'
```

to actually grep something I want to.

This didnt' work properly, so I tried different combination:

```
find . -name "*.js" -exec cat {} \; grep http | grep -shoP 'http.*?[" >]'
```

It is a good one, but we are not yet there... it gives me junk with double quotes and such.

So I've added:

```
find . -name "*.js" -exec cat {} \; grep http | grep -shoP 'http.*?[" >]' |
sed s'/".*//g'
```

This removes the `"` at the end of certain URLs, but something tells me it might break some of them.

The problem left is: I get junk like

```
http"
https"
http'
```

and so on...

All I need is the "real" web URL.

I'll then run it in a sort of loop on a timer to open every single line in Internet Explorer to test if those are actually malicious websites or not (we are dealing with a situation right now).

Comment: Please post a sample input and expected output.

Comment: `open every single line in Internet Explorer to test if those are actually malicious websites or not (we are dealing with a situation right now)`  You're going to kill your computer.

Comment: Dont worry, I wont.

ill use a timer. and winwait from AutoIt.. 

in anycase, I still need help figuring it out how i am suppose to gather the correct url, without the false result.

Thank you!